# my the_content() function in wordpress is not working

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

My the_content() function is not working. please check my code attached below. this code is written in page template.

```
<div class="row marT20" >
    <div class="content">
        <?php 
            while ( have_posts() )
            {
                the_post();
        ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p class="marT20"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

This is not showing any content but title is printing.

**Edit:-**

**i resolved this question myself... that was my fault in writing the functions.php.**

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: what css do you have on the class marT20? Might be displaying none etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code Please with if Condition**

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> // if post exists

<?php the_title(); ?> // title 

<?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?> //content with more option

<?php endwhile; else: ?> //else
**strong text**
<?php echo "Sorry, no posts matched your criteria."; ?></p><?php endif; ?> // print this
```

Answer (score 0):

For your more info:
Apart from `the_content();` you can also use `echo get_the_content();`